# Shared library and .h import in react native

Tags: react-native

I have .so and .h files in a sdk built for android. I want to use it in react native. How can I do it? Is there a way to turn it into a module so I can import and use its functions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use them directly but yes there is way. You need to `Bridge` that files to `js`.

[Helping Material](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)

Comment: With this, you need to create a whole module in java, add functions etc. But I have my functions in .h file as NativeString already. This material is probably not for my question